# Reproduce ARIMA Forecast (Pandas)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, timeserieschart

I am quite new to the ARIMA model, and I have a question on how to analyze the chart of the ACF (autocorrelaction function) according to the lag. Is it correct to take into account the ACF value of 0.5 which corresponds to about 450 lag and then set the arima model on these values?

This is my graph:

[image: acf-lag]

and this is my simple code for arima model:

```
import from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

# fit model
model = ARIMA(df['valore'], order=(400,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())

# plot residual errors
residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
residuals.plot()
pyplot.show()
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
pyplot.show()
print(residuals.describe())
```

Thanks!

P.S. my page in jupyter format and the data (csv) can be found at: [github](https://github.com/bellisanogiu/arimaModel)

Answer (score 1):

In theory it is possible to include an order of 400 in an ARIMA model. In practice that value is astronomically high for an ARIMA model (Anything higher than 3 or 4 is considered unusual in an ARIMA model). I would double check your data and also double check how you are calculating the ACF.

Additionally the p order of the ARIMA(p,d,q) model is usually determined using the PACF, not the ACF. You use the ACF for determining q.

Comment: - I entered my code and my data on [github](https://github.com/bellisanogiu/arimaModel)

Comment: - for each day is: x = the sum of the 5 securities with the highest increase + the sum of the 5 securities with the worst decrease

- at the moment I do not know how to calculate the Partial ACF, but I will look for it.

- how do I use ACF to calculate q? I based myself on this source: [ACF to calculate d](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/)

Tanks